# SQLite Query is slow on iOS, and I have no clue why

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have an app that is offline capable, and makes changes to the database from both local and remote sources. I have a metrics query that I need to run every time we write to the database (live updating of the dashboard), and since it can be done locally or remotely, it probably should be triggered by the database.

Basically, every time a transaction finishes, I run the following SQL:

```
- (NSString *)selectDashboardActivities {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT a.*, f.*, p.*, r.*, phys.*, account.*, t.*, s.*, t_i.*, a_i.*, c.*, consent.*, therapy.*, indication.*,"
                                                  " (SELECT CASE"
                                                  "  WHEN ar.resource_cust_num = user.custno THEN %d"
                                                  "  WHEN aardt.territory IS NOT NULL        THEN %d"
                                                  "  WHEN aardt.territory IS NULL            THEN %d"
                                                  "  ElSE %d"
                                                  " END) AS file_scope"
                                                  " FROM PT_ACTIVITY a"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_ACTIVITY_TYPE_STATUS  s          ON  a.activity_type_status_id    = s.activity_type_status_id"
                                                  "                                                AND s.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  "                                                AND s.closed_flag                IN %@"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_ACTIVITY_TYPE         t          ON  a.activity_type_id           = t.activity_type_id"
                                                  "                                                AND t.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_ACTIVITY_RESOURCE     ar         ON  a.activity_id                = ar.activity_id"
                                                  "                                                AND ar.active_flag               = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_FILE                  f          ON  a.file_id                    = f.file_id"
                                                  "                                                AND f.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_PATIENT               p          ON  f.patient_id                 = p.patient_id"
                                                  "                                                AND p.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_RESOURCE              r          ON  ar.resource_cust_num         = r.sold_to_cust_num"
                                                  "                                                AND r.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_AARDT                 aardt      ON  a.rdt_key                    = aardt.rdt_key"
                                                  "                                                AND aardt.active_flag            = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_THERAPY               therapy    ON  f.therapy_id                 = therapy.therapy_id"
                                                  "                                                AND therapy.active_flag          = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_ICON                  a_i        ON  t.icon_id                    = a_i.icon_id"
                                                  "                                                AND a_i.active_flag              = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_ICON                  t_i        ON  therapy.icon_id              = t_i.icon_id"
                                                  "                                                AND t_i.active_flag              = 'Y'"
                                                  " CROSS JOIN PT_USER                  user       ON  user.user_id                 = %@"
                                                  "                                                AND user.active_flag             = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT_TYPE act        ON  a.activity_type_id           = act.activity_type_id"
                                                  "                                                AND act.primary_flag             = 'Y'"
                                                  "                                                AND act.active_flag              = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT      ac         ON  a.activity_id                = ac.activity_id"
                                                  "                                                AND ac.activity_contact_type_id  = act.activity_contact_type_id"
                                                  "                                                AND ac.active_flag               = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_PHYSICIAN             phys       ON  ac.contact_no                = phys.contact_no"
                                                  "                                                AND phys.active_flag             = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_ACCOUNT               account    ON  a.sold_to_cust_num           = account.sold_to_cust_num"
                                                  "                                                AND account.sold_to_cust_num     = account.ship_to_cust_num"
                                                  "                                                AND account.active_flag          = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_FILE_CONSIDERATION    fc         ON  f.file_id                    = fc.file_id"
                                                  "                                                AND fc.active_flag               = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_CONSIDERATION         c          ON  fc.consideration_id          = c.consideration_id"
                                                  "                                                AND c.active_flag                = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_CONSENT               consent    ON  p.patient_id                 = consent.patient_id"
                                                  "                                                AND consent.active_flag          = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_FILE_INDICATION       fi         ON  f.file_id                    = fi.file_id"
                                                  "                                                AND fi.active_flag               = 'Y'"
                                                  " LEFT  JOIN PT_INDICATION            indication ON  indication.indication_id     = fi.indication_id"
                                                  "                                                AND indication.active_flag       = 'Y'"
                                                  " WHERE date(max(a.activity_date, ifnull(a.client_updated_date, a.activity_date)), 'unixepoch') > date('now', 'unixepoch', '-120 day')"
                                                  " AND a.active_flag = 'Y'"
                                                  " AND ar.resource_cust_num IN %@",
                                                 FileScopeMyFile,
                                                 FileScopeTerritory,
                                                 FileScopeDistrict,
                                                 FileScopeUnknown,
                                                 self.filter.closedFlagString,
                                                 [MDTAuthenticationManager authToken].userIdNumber,
                                                 self.filter.resourcesString
    ];
}
```

The `FileScope` arguments are enums, the rest are strings. The `self.filter.resourcesString` could be a string like `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and currently can contain between 1-1000 resources. Running with 1 resource is faster, but not significantly.

Running `explain query plan` on SQLite gives me this:

```
0| 0| 0|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY AS a USING INDEX PT_ACTIVITY_IDX7 (ACTIVE_FLAG=?) (~1049 rows)
0| 1| 1|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY_TYPE_STATUS AS s USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0| 0| 0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0| 2| 2|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY_TYPE AS t USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0| 3| 3|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY_RESOURCE AS ar USING INDEX PT_ACTIVITY_RESOURCE_IDX1 (ACTIVITY_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0| 0| 0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0| 4| 4|SEARCH TABLE PT_FILE AS f USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_PT_FILE_1 (FILE_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0| 5| 5|SEARCH TABLE PT_PATIENT AS p USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_PT_PATIENT_1 (PATIENT_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0| 6| 6|SEARCH TABLE PT_RESOURCE AS r USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_PT_RESOURCE_1 (SOLD_TO_CUST_NUM=?) (~1 rows)
0| 7| 7|SEARCH TABLE PT_AARDT AS aardt USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0| 8| 8|SEARCH TABLE PT_THERAPY AS therapy USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0| 9| 9|SEARCH TABLE PT_ICON AS a_i USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|10|10|SEARCH TABLE PT_ICON AS t_i USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|11|11|SEARCH TABLE PT_USER AS user USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (USER_ID=? AND ACTIVE_FLAG=?) (~7 rows)
0|12|12|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT_TYPE AS act USING INDEX PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT_TYPE_ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID (ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0|13|13|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT AS ac USING INDEX PT_ACTIVITY_CONTACT_PK (ACTIVITY_ID=? AND ACTIVITY_CONTACT_TYPE_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0|14|14|SEARCH TABLE PT_PHYSICIAN AS phys USING INDEX PT_PHYSICIAN_IDX5 (CONTACT_NO=?) (~2 rows)
0|15|15|SEARCH TABLE PT_ACCOUNT AS account USING INDEX PT_ACCOUNT_IDX2 (SOLD_TO_CUST_NUM=?) (~2 rows)
0|16|16|SEARCH TABLE PT_FILE_CONSIDERATION AS fc USING INDEX PT_FILE_CONSIDERATION_FILE_ID (FILE_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0|17|17|SEARCH TABLE PT_CONSIDERATION AS c USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|18|18|SEARCH TABLE PT_CONSENT AS consent USING INDEX PT_CONSENT_IDX1 (PATIENT_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0|19|19|SEARCH TABLE PT_FILE_INDICATION AS fi USING INDEX PT_FILE_INDICATION_FILE_ID (FILE_ID=?) (~2 rows)
0|20|20|SEARCH TABLE PT_INDICATION AS indication USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0| 0| 0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
```

If I understand the query plan, the proper indexes should be in place.

On an iOS device, this query takes 8-12 seconds. I need it to take less than 1, preferably less than 0.5 seconds. I do need all of these tables to generate the proper dashboard items. The first table `PT_ACTIVITY` has 4500 activities in it. The tables are ordered by what I have experimentally found to be the fastest order.

Does anyone have any advice for how I can speed up this query? I'm running out of ideas and sanity... Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're joining 20 tables in one query and you wonder why it's slow?

Comment: @rmaddy That's pretty rude. I don't have any other choice in order to accomplish business' needs.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be rude. It's just a simple fact that a 20 table join running on a mobile device can only be made so fast. It all depends on how many rows are in each table. Plus your `where` clause is doing date calculations which are always slow too.

Comment: @rmaddy I could try to denormalize in a MongoDB styled approach, but that would require me to make an entire process for converting between the remote sync format and our local denormalized database (and back). I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to diagnose the precise source of the performance issue without doing some experimentation with the database, but a couple of reactions looking at that SQL:

1. Certainly the number of tables could be the problem. You might want to temporarily try reducing the number of tables with which you join and see if that changes the performance notably. If so, you can retrieve your data using multiple `SELECT` statements.
2. You're returning a lot of data, too (all columns from all of the tables). We don't know what's in these tables, but you might contemplate only returning the columns you need.

   Notably, if you have any `BLOB` columns, that can seriously impact performance.
3. All of your joins are either outer joins or cross joins. Any reason you don't use inner joins?

   - Do you really need to do all of those outer joins (which are notoriously inefficient; can any of them be replaced with inner joins)?
   - All of those cross joins are curious. Why cross joins?
4. I hesitate to say this given that we don't a sense of your data model, but you might want to carefully consider the order by which you retrieve data. For example, based upon your plan, it looks like `PT_ACTIVITY_RESOURCE` (which is filtered by the `ar.resource_cust_num` in the `WHERE` clause) might be a better table to `SELECT` from, and then start doing your joins from there. It's hard to say without knowing how many records you have in all of these various tables, but you should probably be first selecting on whatever tables most narrowly define the result set and join from there.

   By the way, if you keep it the way it is, you might want to move the `ar.resource_cust_num IN %@` from the `WHERE` clause into the `JOIN ... ON ...` clause. That might have a significant impact on performance.
5. I'd try temporarily removing the `file_scope` clause or simplify the date logic in the `WHERE` clause, to see if either of those are resulting in any strange unintended performance penalties.

It's really hard to diagnose this on the basis of the information provided, but those are a few things to consider. But in terms of a basic strategy, I'd be inclined to slowly start simplifying the SQL and see if you can identify what precisely is the source of the performance hit.

Comment: those are all great points to consider. The reason I used `cross join` was because I thought they accomplished the same behavior as a `join` or `inner join`, but it enforced the order like a `left join`. Allowing the query optimizer to do its thing was not working in my initial attempt, but perhaps since updating my version and using the `analyze` command, things may be different.

Comment: I'd suggest reverting back to inner joins for now. As the SQLite docs say, "Avoid using CROSS JOIN except in specific situations where manual control of the query optimizer is desired. Avoid using CROSS JOIN early in the development of an application as doing so is a premature optimization. The special handling of CROSS JOIN is an SQLite-specific feature and is not a part of standard SQL."

Comment: I'll take it for a swing and see what happens :)